# What the difference between these two connectors?

Tags: connector

I intend to use [this power connector](http://ro.farnell.com/molex/46015-0403/header-vertical-dual-row-4-way/dp/1717563) with its corresponding connector. Can someone tell me the mechanical difference between these two connectors:

[MOLEX  39-01-3048](http://ro.farnell.com/molex/39-01-3048/housing-rcpt-dual-row-4way-crimp/dp/1697118?MER=sy-me-pd-mi-acce)

[MOLEX  39-01-2040](http://ro.farnell.com/molex/39-01-2040/receptacle-mini-fit-4way-crimp/dp/151867?MER=sy-me-pd-mi-acce)

One has pull tabs and the other doesn't, but I do not understand what are pull tabs. Can someone explain it to me and, maybe, offer an image?

Comment: Why not look at the datasheet from Molex?

Comment: @Tyler It's not clear to me.

Comment: There are mechanical drawing on Molex's web site too. One difference is the UL Rating of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really look at the Molex datasheet for this, it even has 3D and 2D drawings of the part.

The pull tabs are little ledge of plastic that stick out on the sides of the connector for better grip. The reason they also offer them without pull tabs is in case you have connectors side by side for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This snip from [one of the Molex PDF drawing files](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/039013048_sd.pdf) shows the difference if side pull tabs or not.

[image]

All the parts will have the pull ledges on the top and bottom. Ones with side pull tabs permit a greater ease in grabbing onto the part to remove it from the mated part.

Sometimes this type of connector is used side by side with another. In that case the side pull tabs would interfere with the other connector and in that case you would choose to use one without the side tabs.

Answer (score 0):

After viewing the 3D models, I found out that the pull tabs (on the top margins of the connector) are basically wider on MOLEX 39-01-2040.